# ‘Quality’=‘action’=‘state’

Tags: abstract-nouns

Can ‘quality,’ ‘action’ and ‘state’ have the same sense?

It goes in this way:

1. The quality is the action
2. The quality is the state
3. The state is the action

For example:

> Brightness: the quality or state of giving out or reflecting light.

Can giving out or reflecting light not only be action but also quality or state?

Comment: All three statements are grammatical but none of them means anything to the reader unless you illustrate how you would use them. It's like saying **thoughts are the answer**. The question becomes what thoughts, and the answer to what.

Comment: @Ronald Sole I did my best.

Comment: Your best does not tell us exactly what it is that you are trying to establish. Trying using your examples in sentences that illustrate their meaning.

Comment: Language is not math. Your sentences do not communicate anything.

Comment: I believe @user44637 is asking about these terms as used in dictionaries, where definitions commonly say, "the quality or state of...", and they're asking what, if any, the difference is between them. Am I right?

Comment: @gotube Yeah, you’re right.

Answer (score 1):

The words "quality" and "state" are used a bit oddly in dictionaries.

A "bicycle" you can easily say is a vehicle, but what's a "vehicle"? Maybe an instrument of conveyance. Then what's is an "instrument"? And it goes on until you're left without a category noun to describe the noun you're defining. In these situations, dictionary writers often use "best fit" words like "quality", "state", and "condition", among others. They often use more than one, as in your example, because neither is exactly right, and using more than one is a way to "fudge" it.

So, in dictionary definitions, it's not worth worrying about the precise meaning of those words. Outside dictionary definitions, however, these words all have distinct meanings and are not at all equivalent.